# Delete the first record from a fasta file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, biopython

I have a small fasta file in the following format:

```
>gene_1 + other data
seq 1
>gene_1 + other data
seq2
>gene_1 + other data
seq3
```

I would like to remove the first element of the file. This is part of a large Python script, and once I have worked with that seq, and extracted the interesting part of it, I would like to remove it from the file. Eventually, the file will be emptied so I can delete it from the folder.
As I have been using Biopython, I was trying to see if I could find a function within Biopython to this but I cannot find any hints on how to delete records from a fasta file. As SeqIO has a kind of list, I tried with the `list.remove(list[0])` method but it doesn't work. Any idea on this? I case someone ask me to post the script, the script is about 200 lines long.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something simple to get you started:

```
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO

filename = sys.argv[1]

sequences = []

for not_first, record in enumerate(SeqIO.parse(filename, 'fasta')):
    if not_first:
        sequences.append(record)

SeqIO.write(sequences, 'truncated-' + filename, 'fasta')
```

It's not optimal for lengthy sequences nor a large number of sequences where we want to avoid reading them all into memory but rather just process one at a time.  But it's a place to get started.

Comment: Yeap I was thinking on those terms. I thought that biopython may have something to help with the matter. I use list(SeqIO.parse) but it doesn't have all the feature that lists have. Thanks, a lot for your help.